# Best practice to identify and deal with idle actors in Akka

Tags: akka, actor

I'm new to the Akka framework and I'm building a group chat application with it. My application may have 10 million actor instances (an actor instance for each group chat) of the same type, only 5% of which are highly active, and 60% of which can be idle (not receiving any messages) for days.

I want to know:

1. Is there any best practice to identify these idle actors?
2. What is the best practice to deal with them? Is stopping them enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any best practice to identify these idle actors?

An actor's `ActorContext` has a [`setReceiveTimeout`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#receive-timeout) method that defines an inactivity threshold for the actor: if the actor hasn't received a message in the given amount of time, then an `akka.actor.ReceiveTimeout` message is sent to the actor. For example:

```scala
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ReceiveTimeout }
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class ChatActor extends Actor {
  context.setReceiveTimeout(2 hours)

  def receive = {
    case ReceiveTimeout =>
      // do something

    // other case clauses
  }
}
```

The above `ChatActor` will receive a `ReceiveTimeout` message if it hasn't received a message for two hours. (However, as the documentation states: "the receive timeout might fire and enqueue the `ReceiveTimeout` message right after another message was enqueued; hence it is **not guaranteed** that upon reception of the receive timeout there must have been an idle period beforehand as configured via this method.")

---

> What is the best practice to deal with them?

It's a good idea to stop inactive actors; otherwise you could have a memory leak. Here are a few approaches for stopping these actors:

- The inactive actor throws an exception, which is handled in a [supervisor strategy](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/fault-tolerance.html) defined in the actor's parent. In the supervisor strategy, the parent stops the idle actor (e.g., via `context stop sender()`).
- The inactive actor sends its `self` reference to a "reaper" actor that collects references to idle actors and culls (i.e., stops) these actors on a periodic basis (perhaps using a [scheduler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scheduler.html)).
- The inactive actor stops itself (via `context stop self`).

More information about stopping actors is found [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#stopping-actors).

---

> Is stopping them enough?

When an actor is stopped, its `ActorRef` essentially becomes invalid. From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#stop-hook):

> After stopping an actor, its `postStop` hook is called, which may be used e.g. for deregistering this actor from other services. This hook is guaranteed to run after message queuing has been disabled for this actor, i.e. messages sent to a stopped actor will be redirected to the `deadLetters` of the `ActorSystem`.

At this point, the underlying actor instance to which the now-stale `ActorRef` points is eligible for garbage collection. In other words, an actor must be stopped in order for it to be eligible for garbage collection. Therefore, in regard to freeing up memory, stopping the actor is enough. You could also remove the invalid `ActorRef` itself after the actor has been stopped. Note that [removing an `ActorRef`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#actor-lifecycle) does not automatically stop the actor:

> It is important to note that Actors do not stop automatically when no longer referenced, every Actor that is created must also explicitly be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there any best practice to identify these idle actors?

The only way is to make each actor to keep the time when it was active last time. Then, to speedup investigation of the longest inactive actor, you can organize an index-like structure, e.g. PriorityQueue. Then a dedicated actor periodically awakes and cleans that structure from actors which are idle longer than some predefined period of time.

2. What is the best practice to deal with them? Is stopping them enough?

An idle actor does not consume any resources except core memory. If you have plenty of memory, the best practice is to do nothing. If you want to save that memory, store actor in database (after some period of inactivity), and then read it from there by demand.

Comment: 1- I should store that 
"index-like structure" in their parent actor?

Comment: in any actor that can periodically awake and clean it.

Comment: 2- Is stopping an actor not enough for releasing its memory?

Comment: Stopping an actor means it stops to handle new messages, it has no effect on occupied memory. Memory is released according to JVM rules: when an actor is no longer referenced and so become garbage.